# Multiple auth methods using AngularFire2

Tags: angular, angularfire2

The AngularFire2 [doc](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/5-user-authentication.md) explains ways to set up login methods using password or federated methods such as Google or Facebook. But I want to set up password login together with federated methods as options. I tried the following without success:

```
const firebaseAuthConfig = {
  provider:[AuthProviders.Google, AuthProviders.Password],
  method: AuthMethods.Redirect
};
```

Is it possible to set up multiple auth methods using AngularFire2? Please advice with a simple piece of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that you can only setup a single authentication method via the module's `initializeApp` call. However, you can specify/override the authentication method when you make the `login` call.

There are examples further down the page in the [document](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/5-user-authentication.md#override-configuration--no-config) to which you have linked:

> ```ts
> // Anonymous
> af.auth.login({
>   provider: AuthProviders.Anonymous,
>   method: AuthMethods.Anonymous,
> });
>
> // Email and password
> af.auth.login({
>   email: 'email@example.com',
>   password: 'password',
> },
> {
>   provider: AuthProviders.Password,
>   method: AuthMethods.Password,
> });
>
> // Social provider redirect
> af.auth.login({
>   provider: AuthProviders.Twitter,
>   method: AuthMethods.Redirect,
> });
>
> // Social provider popup
> af.auth.login({
>   provider: AuthProviders.Github,
>   method: AuthMethods.Popup,
> });
> ```